# Inconsistent display of sheet in swiftUI on Ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I use the modifiers .sheet(isPresented: ) to present a view with SwiftUI.
But the result is not the same on an Iphone or on an Ipad.

Here is the two differents looks : [look on Ipad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnpz3.png) -
[look on Iphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObMxC.png)

I want to have the view on Ipad to have the same look than on Iphone. Is this possible ?
Because now the sheet is divided in two on Ipad(as you can see on the picture)

EDIT:
I added :

```
NavigationView {
     // ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

and it worked but there is still a minor issue : [minor issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3XQG.png)

EDIT : here is the code inside the sheet

```
Form{

            Section(header: Text("Adresse").foregroundColor(Constants.colorTitle).fontWeight(.semibold)) {
                VStack{
                    Text("Vous y êtes presque !").padding(.bottom,5)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showShareFileActivity = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Télécharger le bon de visite à compléter. ").padding().foregroundColor(.white).font(Font.custom("Montserrat-Regular", size: 14)).background(Constants.colorTitle).cornerRadius(5)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showShareFileActivity,
                    content: {
                        ActivityView(activityItems: [self.data] as [Any], applicationActivities: nil) })
                }

                HStack{
                //                        Text(("Adresse du bien"))
                //                        Spacer()
                    TextField("Adresse ", text: $createFileViewModel.file.adresse).font(.system(size: 14)).padding(8).background(Constants.colorLightGrey).background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).strokeBorder(Constants.colorPrimary,lineWidth: 1))
                }
            }


                Section(header: Text("Pièces jointes").foregroundColor(Constants.colorTitle).fontWeight(.semibold)){
                        HStack {
                            Text("Bon de visite rempli")
                            if createFileViewModel.file.urlBonDeViste != "" {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill").foregroundColor(.green).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium))
                            }
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showDocumentPicker = true
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up").font(.system(size: 22, weight: .medium)).padding(.trailing,10)
                            }
                            .sheet(isPresented: $showDocumentPicker, content: {
                                DocumentPicker(urlBonDeVisite: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlBonDeViste, userId: self.session.session!.uid, docId: self.createFileViewModel.file.idDocument)
                            })
                        }

                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            HStack {
                                Text("Plan cadastral")
                                if createFileViewModel.file.urlPlanCadastal != "" {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill").foregroundColor(.green).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium))
                                }

                                Spacer()

                                Button(action: {
                                    self.showImagePicker = true
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up").font(.system(size: 22, weight: .medium)).padding(.trailing,10)
                                }
                                .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, content: {
                                    ImagePicker(isShown: self.$showImagePicker, from: "PlanCadastral", userId: self.session.session!.uid, docId: self.createFileViewModel.file.idDocument, urlPlanCadastral: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlPlanCadastal, urlWebcarto: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlWebcarto, photosSupplementaires: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlsPhotosSupplémentaires)
                                })

                            }
                            if createFileViewModel.file.urlPlanCadastal != "" {
                                RemoteImageProfilePictureMedium(url: createFileViewModel.file.urlPlanCadastal, size: 75, colorStroke: Constants.colorPrimary).padding(.trailing, 5)
                            }
                        }


                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            HStack{

                                Text("Webcarto")
                                if createFileViewModel.file.urlWebcarto != "" {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill").foregroundColor(.green).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium))
                                }

                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.showImagePicker = true
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up").font(.system(size: 22, weight: .medium)).padding(.trailing,10)
                                }
                                .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, content: {
                                    ImagePicker(isShown: self.$showImagePicker, from: "Webcarto", userId: self.session.session!.uid, docId: self.createFileViewModel.file.idDocument, urlPlanCadastral: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlPlanCadastal, urlWebcarto: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlWebcarto, photosSupplementaires: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlsPhotosSupplémentaires)
                                })
                            }

                            if createFileViewModel.file.urlWebcarto != "" {
                                    RemoteImageProfilePictureMedium(url: createFileViewModel.file.urlWebcarto, size: 75, colorStroke: Constants.colorPrimary).padding(.trailing, 5)
                            }

                        }


                        VStack{
                            HStack {
                                Text("Photos supplémentaires")
                                if createFileViewModel.file.urlsPhotosSupplémentaires.count > 0 {
                                    Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill").foregroundColor(.green).font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium))
                                }
                                Spacer()
                                Button(action: {
                                    self.showImagePicker = true
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up").font(.system(size: 22, weight: .medium)).padding(.trailing,10)
                                }
                                .sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker, content: {
                                    ImagePicker(isShown: self.$showImagePicker, from: "PhotosSupplementaires", userId: self.session.session!.uid, docId: self.createFileViewModel.file.idDocument, urlPlanCadastral: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlPlanCadastal, urlWebcarto: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlWebcarto, photosSupplementaires: self.$createFileViewModel.file.urlsPhotosSupplémentaires)
                                })
                            }

                            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                                HStack {
                                    ForEach(createFileViewModel.file.urlsPhotosSupplémentaires, id: \.self) { urlPhoto in
                                        RemoteImageProfilePictureMedium(url: urlPhoto, size: 75, colorStroke: Constants.colorPrimary).padding(.trailing, 5)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }



                        if createFileViewModel.error != "" {
                            Text(createFileViewModel.error).font(.system(size: 14, weight: .semibold)).foregroundColor(.red).padding()
                        }

                        Button(action: createFileViewModel.goToNextStep) {
                            Text("Envoyer le dossier").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity).frame(height: 50).foregroundColor(.white).font(.system(size: 14, weight: .bold)).background(Constants.colorButton).cornerRadius(5)
                        }
                    }



        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        .onAppear(perform: downloadPDF)
```

Comment: Are you using a `navigationView` inside the `.sheet`? Showing some code will be helpful here

Comment: i edited my question, and no i am not using any navigationView

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

On your NavigationView, set a StackNavigationViewStyle as navigationViewStyle:

```swift
NavigationView {
     // ...
}
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

Comment: it worked thanks but there is still a minor issue, i edit my question so that you can see

Comment: What is the minor issue? no padding inside the sheet?